# Flutter filter data list in future builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list which i am using in FutureBuilder like this

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    height: Height * 0.5,
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getCustomerList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          getTake();
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            list = snapshot.data;
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap:(){
                      print(list);
                      print(list.length);
                      var check = list.where((i) => i['give'] > 1).toList();
                      print('list check');
                      print(check);
                      print(check.length);
                      setState(() {
                        list = check;
                      });

                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: Width * 0.45,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        color: Color(0xfffdeced),
                      ),
                      child: Text('filter'),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    height: Height * 0.5,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: list.length,
                      itemBuilder:
                          (BuildContext context,
                          int index) {
                        return list[index]

                        ['customerName']
                            .toString()
                            .contains(searchString)
                            ? GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,

                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      CustomerData(
                                          data: list[index])),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                            const EdgeInsets
                                .only(
                                left: 13,
                                right: 13),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration:
                              BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    top: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors
                                            .grey,
                                        width:
                                        .5)),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding:
                                const EdgeInsets
                                    .all(
                                    13.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                      .spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                          child:
                                          Text(
                                            list[index]['customerName'][0]
                                                .toString(),
                                            style:
                                            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'PoppinsBold'),
                                          ),
                                          backgroundColor:
                                          Color(0xffF7F9F9),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width:
                                          20,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          list[index]['customerName']
                                              .toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily:
                                              'PoppinsMedium'),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '${list[index]['give'] - list[index]['take']}',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily:
                                          'PoppinsMedium',
                                      color: list[index]['give'] - list[index]['take'] < 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                            : Container();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          else
            return Center(
              heightFactor: 1,
              widthFactor: 1,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 70,
                width: 70,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 2.5,
                ),
              ),
            );
        }),
  ),
),
```

You can see on gesture detector i am filtering list but where and its working also but its not changing the state.

As you can see i am printing `list.length` its showing 2 after where future where i can see its showing length 1 its mean its working perfectly fine. But how is it possible to change its state ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use SetState you practically call your FutureBuilder once more. So you first set list from snapshot.data and show them. Then your gesture detector filter your list and call setState. setState call FutureBuilder who set list as snapshot.data again.  If you add some print after list = snapshot.data, for expample

```
list = snapshot.data;
print('suprise');
print(list);
```

you will see what's going on.

The solution is to set some filter, not to the list, but to the snapshot.data. So you must add some new variable, that have info about how to filter data, higher than FutureBuilder and set it in setstate. And use that variable to build snapshot.data in getCustomerList